# Prototypical inheritance is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, javascript-inheritance

```
var oldobj = {
  firstm: function () { console.log("firstm"); },
  secondm: function () { console.log("secondm"); }
};

var newobj= Object(oldobj);

newobj.thirdm = function () { console.log("thirdm"); };

oldobj.fourthm = function () { console.log("4thm"); };

newobj.fifthm = function () { console.log("5thm"); };

oldobj.fifthm(); // logs "5thm" in console
```

According to prototypical inheritance, the oldobj has no link to newobj functions. But in the above example how is the oldobj able to access fifthm() of newobj?

Comment: Are you confusing `Object()` with `Object.create()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no inheritance here. There's not even two objects.

```
var newobj= Object(oldobj);
```

makes `newobj` equal to `oldobj`.

From the [MDN on Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

> If the value is an object already, it will return the value

Prototypal inheritance in JavaScript is done *very* differently. I'd suggest you read [this introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Prototype-based_programming).

As pointed out by Felix Kling, it's possible that what you wanted was [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var newobj= Object.create(oldobj);
```

Note that this doesn't make classes, it's more a kind of instanciation than an inheritance if you don't define two prototypes.